# 8e6 R3000 + iOS devices

Tags: internet, apple-ios

Our organization uses the 8e6 R3000 filter for internet authentication and filtering. We recently got wireless routers installed (yeah!) and our laptops work great with it, but our iOS devices don't because the R3000 uses a java applet to remain authenticated.

As it stands now, every ~30 seconds when you try to load a webpage it brings up the authentication page and non-webpage things (mail, apps, etc) don't work except for those 30 seconds. As you can see, this gets *really* annoying. Is there some way to have the iOS devices remain authenticated? I'm not the head IT guy, and don't have the privileges to change anything on the R3000, and quite frankly our head guys don't care. Help anyone?

Comment: For anyone trying to work on this [here is documentation](http://www.m86security.com/support/r3000/documentation.asp) for the filter gizmo. (gag)

Answer (score 5):

We use the R3000. It has *many* other shortcomings besides the Java requirement.  For "unsupported" devices, you can configure an sub IP Group Filtering Profile.  This will apply a specific filtering ruleset to all devices in this group, without authentication.  This requires your IT department's involvement.  They would need identify and place "mobile" devices within a specific subnet and alter the R3000 rules to service this group in a manner that works for non-Java devices.

That being said, if you're not part of the IT department, and they won't assist, it will be *quite* difficult to configure the R3000.  You could instead just connect your iPhone to a Proxy/VPN outside.  This may be a policy violation, so you would need to determine your best option.

Comment: thanks! (It won't let me upvote or mark as answer, or I would). I'll try to talk them into doing that.